# Docker Image For Deploying DotNet Core Output to Firebase

Tags: firebase, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm struggling to create a BitBucket Pipeline script which can compile a DotNet Core application, run it and then deploy the output html files to Firebase using the CLI.

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet build MySolution.sln
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
           caches:
             - dotnetcore
           script:
            - dotnet restore
            - dotnet build MySolution.sln
            - cd MySolution
            - dotnet run MySolution.
            - npm install -g firebase-tool
            - firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
```

The image `microsoft/dotnet:sdk` doesn't contain npm or the Firebase-Tools package I require. I'm struggling to find an alternative Docker Image which contains both dotnet and npm / Firebase-Tools. Is there a simpler way to deploy the output of the application to Firebase directly from BitBucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should dig into the multi-step approach of Bitbucket pipelines. There you will be able to run each of the steps with different docker images.

More documentation you may find at Bitbucket [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_step)

For example:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk
        script:
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet build
          - dotnet publish -o /out -c Release
        artifacts:
          - out/**
    - step:
        name: Run npm
        image: node:8
        script:
          - npm install -g firebase-tool
          - firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
    - step
        name: Run app
        image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk
        script:
          - dotnet run MySolution .
```